# Adding elements to lists inside a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have an empty list of 5 lists:

```
a=[[]] * 5
>>> a
[[], [], [], [], []]
```

Now I want to keep adding numbers, characters and strings in each of these lists, based on certain conditions.

Keeping my problem statement simple, how do I append a number to one of the specific elements of a?

If I use...
`a[**2**]+=[88]`

... I get

```
>>> a
[[88], [88], [88], [88], [88]]
```

This means there's no significance of the "2" I used as index to set a[2]
That's not what I wanted. I wanted a = [[], [], [88], [], []]

Comment: "This means there's no significance of the "2" I used as index to set a[2]" no, the significance is exactly what you expected: you mutated the object at index `2`, it just happens that due to the way you created your list, every index is referring to the same object.

Comment: Consider: `x = []; a =[x, x ,x]; a[2] += [88]; print(x, a)`

Comment: The way initializing a=[[]] * 5 will give a list of lists were all the lists point to same memory. So you can try  a= [[] for x in range(5)] to get the list which are independent..